# php gcm save registration token

Tags: php, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

hello I'm working with gcm , service worker I'm getting registration id of each user and everything , now what I want is how to save the registration token and store it to my database using mysql and php. any help would be appreciated

Comment: What is your question or issue?

Comment: I want some code sir to store the token to my database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'm guessing is you want to store the GCM Token from the device on your MySql database. I will give an example with User table for sending notifications...
So, what you can simply do is this:

1. **Send the token to your server** using Volley Library (JSONObjectRequest).
2. On the PHP Script manage retreive this token and execute a query like (for example)

`INSERT INTO User (email, fcm_token) VALUES ($email, $fmc_token);`

4. Then you can get that token if you want to send notifications or update your UI only executing a 'SELECT fcm_token FROM User'.

Here an example of how to use Volley:
http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

**EDIT:**

You should now use FCM instead of GCM...

Comment: `('email', 'fcm_token')` those should not be regular quotes `'` but backticks `\`` - your answer will fail them.

Comment: It's just an example, actually he should use prepared statements...

Comment: so why give them bad syntax in the first place? If I had a nickel for everytime someone told me what you just said, I'd have enough to buy me a pound of weed. Not to mention for future visitors who will think your syntax is correct.

Comment: haha relax bro, now he knows, whatevere I will edit the answer

Comment: *lol* I am relaxed ;-) I got my weed.

Comment: and how can i get the id registration in adnroid java? thanks!

Comment: @AlbertoAcuña you can get the Firebase Cloud Message token by invoking `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken().await()`. Remember to add the coroutines extensions for Google Play libs to use `await` instead of an async callback.